# SSRS report unknown item changing my totals

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

[image]

I am creating new reports to be able to automate them from SSRS, but this report compared to the actual invoices and old report is off.

In the picture the left numbers are copy and pasted from the new report I created, and the right are numbers I manually entered next to it with the totals of both on the bottom created by an equation and you can see they come out with different totals even though they are the exact same numbers.

I checked to see if it was something with how they were rounding but I found that unless I tell it to round with an expression it won't automatically do it. I've also tried increasing the decimal places to see what happens but doesn't change the total. Tried to create a custom number field in the text box properties but nothing I've done has resulted in anything different. Not sure where to go from here since the totals are usually only a couple cents off which would be caused by any of my connections, but a couple cents add up at the end. I appreciate any advice of what my next step should be.

Comment: remove all the formatting excel and show all decimal places. I pretty sure you'll find the numbers are not exactly to 2 decimals. If that does not help, edit this question and show your report design and **all** the expressions used, including detail and group totals rows. There should be nothing complicated here, so the answer is probably simple. Also, supply some sample data ( as text, not as an image) so we can reproduce if required.